# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\add_news.php on line 52

Tags: php, mysql

EDIT:Im the author -So i have done all this you guys that telled me and the page showed butI AM WRITING AN ARTICLE THEN SHOWS:
Object not found!and in the url adress writes this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF ?>">
```

so this is my problem i used it ago 2 days and the whole worked but i forgot how i fixed mistakely the add_news.php code.**And the problem is:`Notice: Undefined variable: submit in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\add_news.php on line 7`

Here is my config.php for news:

`<?php// Set Mysql Variables//Change the following$dbhost="localhost";$dbusername="top";$dbpassword="top";$dbname="top";// Don't touch here anything.// Connect to Mysql$connect = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword);//Select the correct database.mysql_select_db($dbname,$connect) or die ("Could not select database");mysql_query('set names cp1252');?`>AND I ALMOST FORGOT FOR THE SHORT PHP TAGS-I edit all short tags,but again this issue.Should i make a htacces with ALLOW short php tags?

**I TRIED EVERYTHING BUT NOTHING WORKS :x :(**

Comment: You should edit your post so it is readable and makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like either you have an opening bracet in config.php that isnt closed or your server is not set up to support short tags.

try changing:

```
<?
}//end of else
?>
```

To

```
<?php
}//end of else
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the php file in UTF-8 format .

update the database column in UTF-8 format and check

Answer (score 0):

add space between php tag and comment //

```
<?php // Set Mysql Variables
```

instead

```
<?php// Set Mysql Variables
```